# Can I make an assumption about arbitrary numbers in a proof?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assume  $ x_1, x_2... x_{10} $ are different numbers and $ y_1, y_2... y_{10} $ are some arbitrary numbers. Prove that there exists some unique polynomial of degree not exceeding 9 such that:

$P(x_1)=y_1,P(x_2)=y_2...P(x_{10})=y_{10}$

Proof to the problem rests on the assumption that there is some polynomial Q(x) of degree not exceeding 9 such that:

$ Q(x_1)=y_1,Q(x_2)=y_2...Q(x_{10})=y_{10}$.

Is it a valid assumption in a proof of this sort?

Comment: Where $Q$ is what exactly? A polynomial? Of degree less than or equal to 9? If so, then no this only gets half the proof: that any such polynomial is unique. To assert the existence of a thing you want to prove the existence of invalidates any proof of existence.

Comment: Yes, a polynomial of degree < 9. Your second sentence is incomprehensible to me. Could you elaborate?

Comment: No, you may not assume anything that you can't prove (or your lecturer / teacher hasn't proved). Can you prove that $Q$ exists? (Hint: try to find $P_1$ with $P_1(x_1) = y_1$ and $P_2$ with $P_2(x_2) = y_2$, and combine them somehow to find $P$ with $P(x_1) = y_1$ and $P(x_2) = y_2$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect because proving the existence of such a polynomial is an important part of the problem you are working on.

Here is a hint: Suppose you were given the problem with only two pairs $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. Then how would you find such a polynomial? Think in terms of a straight line. You are given two distinct (since $x_1 \neq x_2$) points so there always exists a straight line that passes through these points and the equation of that line will be polynomial of the required degree.

If you were given $3$ points then a parabola passes through it and so on.

If you are still unable to make progress then look for [Lagrange Interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove two things: that there is such a polynomial and that there is only one.  To prove that there is one, you can show a way to construct it.  Can you find a way to construct a polynomial $Q_1(x)$ of degree not exceeding $9$ such that $Q_1(x_1)=y_1,Q_1(x_2)=0...Q_1(x_{10})=0$?  Now if you construct nine other polynomials with similar conditions and add them together, you get the $Q(x)$ you want.  Linearity is wonderful.  Now you need to prove it unique.  Assume there is another polynomial $R(x)$ of degree at most $9$ that satisfies the requirement.  How many roots does $R(x)-Q(x)$ have?